# What is the difference between "page_stories" and "post_stories" in the Facebook Insights API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-page, facebook-insights

I'm currently creating an analytics tool and I'm a bit confused about the API descriptions in the Insights API.

For the value "page_stories" the API says: "The number of stories created about your Page (Stories)" and for the (real-time) "post_stories" it says:"The number of stories generated about your Page post ('Stories')".

I'm understanding the difference between the page and post but thought that "page_stories" also measures the stories created from a page post. But after re-reading it a lot of times, I'm now confused and think that "page_stories" only measures stories which are really related to the Page itself and not to the posts.

- Is my assumption correct that the insights value "page_stories" is only measuring Stories only about the Page without the posts and the value "post_stories" is measuring the stories generated about this specific post?
- If this is true it would lead to a second question: How can I calculate the created stories for a facebook page including page and posts for a specific date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Page Stories:** The number of stories created about your Page. Stories include:

- Likes of your Page;
- Likes, comments on, or shares of your Page posts;
- Answers to a Question you’ve asked;
- Responses to your Event;
- Mentions of your Page;
- Tags of your Page in a photo;
- Check-ins or Recommendations of your Place.

**Post Stories:** The number of stories generated about your Page post. Stories include:

- Likes, comments on, or shares your Page post;
- Answers a question you’ve asked;
- Responds to your event.

*Source: http://www.jonloomer.com/2012/09/11/facebook-insights-glossary/*

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what i was searching for. Do you have any source for this ? Facebook?